# C/C++ Converting a 64 bit integer to char array

Tags: c++, gcc, memory, 64-bit

I have the following simple program that uses a union to convert between a 64 bit integer and its corresponding byte array:

```
union u
{
  uint64_t ui;
  char c[sizeof(uint64_t)];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  u test;
  test.ui = 0x0123456789abcdefLL;
  for(unsigned int idx = 0; idx < sizeof(uint64_t); idx++)
    {
      cout << "test.c[" << idx << "] = 0x" << hex << +test.c[idx] << endl;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

What I would expect as output is:

```
test.c[0] = 0xef
test.c[1] = 0xcd
test.c[2] = 0xab
test.c[3] = 0x89
test.c[4] = 0x67
test.c[5] = 0x45
test.c[6] = 0x23
test.c[7] = 0x1
```

But what I actually get is:

```
test.c[0] = 0xffffffef
test.c[1] = 0xffffffcd
test.c[2] = 0xffffffab
test.c[3] = 0xffffff89
test.c[4] = 0x67
test.c[5] = 0x45
test.c[6] = 0x23
test.c[7] = 0x1
```

I'm seeing this on Ubuntu LTS 14.04 with GCC.

I've been trying to get my head around this for some time now. Why are the first 4 elements of the char array displayed as 32 bit integers, with 0xffffff prepended to them? And why only the first 4, why not all of them?
Interestingly enough, when I use the array to write to a stream (which was the original purpose of the whole thing), the correct values are written. But comparing the array char by char obviously leads to problems, since the first 4 chars are not equal 0xef, 0xcd, and so on.

Comment: cast as `(char*)` and then read 4 bytes...?

Comment: No change. Besides, I can always mask the char with 0x000000ff to get the expected values. I'm just interested in the reason behind this behavior.

Comment: Apparently your implementation has signed chars.  Normal integer promotion will sign-extend.

Comment: I think it's because test.c is type `int` which will either be a 16-bit, 32-bit or 64-bit word depending on the architecture the kernel is built for... Somewhat of a guess though, I need to dust off my C++ hat! Also further to @ewd's comment, you may want to specifically cast it as `(unsigned int)` or `(unsigned char)`.

Comment: Hey, that solved it! Thanks!

Comment: A note on defining sizes based on `sizeof`: If you use `sizeof(<variable name>);`  instead of `sizeof(<variable type>);` the change cascades down to the dependents if you change the type of the source variable later. In this case ` char c[sizeof(ui)];` will always have the same size as `ui`. Ditto `sizeof(test.ui)` in the for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `char` is not the right thing to do since it could be `signed` or `unsigned`. Use `unsigned char`.

```
union u
{
  uint64_t ui;
  unsigned char c[sizeof(uint64_t)];
};
```

Comment: That solves it. The problem is now that writing the array to a stream gives errors as the streams accept only `char *` and not `unsigned char *` plus I don't really like using `reinterpret_cast` all the time...

Comment: @tickferno,if you need help with that, please post another question that specifically addresses the streaming issue.

Answer (score 2):

`char` gets promoted to an `int` because of the prepended unary `+` operator. . Since your `chars` are `signed`, any element with the highest by set to `1` is interpreted as a negative number and promoted to an integer with the same negative value. There are a few different ways to solve this:

1. Drop the `+`: `... << test.c[idx] << ...`. This may print the char as a character rather than a number, so is probably not a good solution.
2. Declare `c` as `unsigned char`. This will promote it to an `unsigned int`.
3. Explicitly cast `+test.c[idx]` before it is passed: `... << (unsigned char)(+test.c[idx]) << ...`
4. Set the upper bytes of the integer to zero using binary `&`: `... << +test.c[idx] & 0xFF << ...`. This will only display the lowest-order byte no matter how the `char` is promoted.

Comment: char is not promoted in the << operator, it is due to the unary + operator. This can be easily seen if you drop the unary + from the code.

Comment: Dropping the unary + operator prints the char "directly", but I'm interested in their actual hex value (the hex operator doesn't help otherwise). Also the following fails: `test.c[0] == 0xef`

Comment: Good call. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use either unsigned char or use `test.c[idx] & 0xff` to avoid sign extension when a `char value > 0x7f` is converted to int.

Answer (score 0):

It is unsigned char vs signed char and its casting to integer

Answer (score 0):

The unary plus causes the `char` to be promoted to a `int` (integral promotion). Because you have signed chars the value will be used as such and the other bytes will reflect that.

It is not true that only the four are ints, they all are. You just don't see it from the representtion since the leading zeroes are not shown.

Either use `unsigned char`s or `& 0xff` for promotion to get the desired result.